# pymogno update_many if X not in obj

Tags: pymongo

I have an object which looks like this:

```
username: username
ip: ip address
country: country
# vpn: boolean
```

not every obj has the `vpn` key yet and I am trying to update all the documents without them, however right now I am just iterating over every document and when I have to restart it's quite a pain cause I also have to make an API call to get the vpn boolean. (which it will make a call even if the `vpn` key already exists, costs a lot of time.)

Is there a way to check if `collection.update_many()` has the `vpn: boolean` key if. if not: continue, else: pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether a field is present, use the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator, e.g.

```
collection.update_many({'vpn': {'$exists': True}}, {<update operation>})
```